# Install a RPM from build context without copying it first

Tags: docker, dockerfile, images

During dockerbuild, I'd like to install a (rather big) RPM from build context/host without copying it first into the image in order to keep my image small.
Ideally, there would be a way to read a file directly from build context.

What are my options (beside using a HTTP server on the host)?
What are the best practices for this use-case?

Comment: Do you just want a file from the RPM?

Comment: @mikequentel Nope, I'd like to install the RPM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using buildkit, you can mount from the build context with `type=bind` to access files without including them in your resulting image.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3
FROM base
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=./rpms/,target=/rpms/ \
    yum install /rpms/package.rpm
```

See [the buildkit docs](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#run---mounttypebind-the-default-mount-type) for more details.